# extended ASCII and windows-1252 (different codes)

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a string, which contains "ä" char.
Default encoding I have is 1252. And the char code is 228.
How can I convert it to extended ASCII in order to have this char with code 132?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var s = "ä";
        var extAscii = Encoding.GetEncoding ("437");
        var enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding (1252);
        var bytes = enc1252.GetBytes (s);
        Console.WriteLine (bytes[0]);
        var newBytes = Encoding.Convert (enc1252, extAscii, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine (newBytes[0]);
```

This code produces 228, 132. The Extended ASCII aka codepage 437 is pretty exotic these days.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is exotic, but looks like not for bar-code printers :)

Comment: In new .NET versions you need this package for Windows-1252: `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use encoding 437 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). This will then correctly convert the extended ASCII symbol "ä" to the corresponding character in ANSI 1252:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace helloworld
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string text = "ä";

         byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(text);

         var convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),Encoding.GetEncoding(437), bytes);

         Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetString(convertedBytes));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No, Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.ASCII, bytes) gives code "63" (?) instead of "132" (ä).

Comment: Did you try Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) instead of Encoding.Default

Comment: Yes, I have spent all day :)

Comment: Works? It encodes everything up to 127, then what is over 127 is replaced with 63(?)

Comment: You need to use the codepage 437 for this, see @Andrey post as well